# How keep things DRY with afnetworking

Tags: ios, afnetworking, dry

I'm writing a ios app which has to send and receive data from the API at various screens in the app. Currently each view controller is calling this code

```
// AFAppDotNetAPIClient is a subclass of AFHTTPClient, which defines the base URL and default HTTP headers for NSURLRequests it creates
[[AFAppDotNetAPIClient sharedClient] getPath:@"stream/0/posts/stream/global" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"App.net Global Stream: %@", JSON);
} failure:nil];
```

I want to keep things **DRY** and so I created a requested builder and response handler to create request and parse responses. I also want to move all the API calls to one class but since it uses blocks I don't know how do this.

Can someone explain how this is done so I call one method with a enum and some params for request and I probably just get a `NSDictionary` back without having API calls and blocks in all view controllers. Thanks

Comment: you want to keep the things `DRY`, is it library ?   what you want to say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a concern for the Model part of your MVC architecture. The example project has a good implementation of this:

#### Post.h

`+ (void)globalTimelinePostsWithBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *posts, NSError *error))block;`

Define class methods on the model that take care of making requests (translating any method parameters into request params) and serializing objects from the response.

Answer (score 0):

Define your new interface to include your enum, parameters and a block. Define the block to have a `BOOL` (status) and an `NSDictionary` (result). This is basically just simplifying and abstracting the interface away from the client, path and operation. Then in the `success` and `failure` blocks you can call the outer block with appropriate parameters.

The block is required to maintain the asynchronous nature of the interface. You could use a target and selector but that will be more code and less flexible. You can't have the method just return the resulting dictionary.

There are obviously many other options for what parameters to pass to the method and in the block.

Comment: I understand the asynchronous nature. What is the solution you would use as an experience programmer? Because to me it doesn't make sense to repeat write the entire API call in all viewcontrollers!

Comment: You need to call something in each controller. Whether it is the AF client, your intermediate singleton or something else just depends on the level of abstraction you want. I usually use a singleton with methods in terms of my internal model objects and method names which represent the action (you are thinking of using an enum for this). Other options like notifications are messy. Delegation is more code.

Comment: messy but notification might be a solution.

Comment: @carbonr Under no circumstances should you be using notifications for this.